# Firebase Database Querying: return latest added object in which the child has a value

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I'm building an Android application in which the user can track its weight and progress by inserting their weight (optional) AND/OR upload a picture (optional).

```
{
  "users" : {
    "5aHvYy5wTIVAAgdOEso0wr2woHS2" : {
      "firstName" : "Justin",
      "logs" : [ {
        "date" : "16/05/2018",
        "progressPicture" : "http://www.google.com/example.jpg",
        "weight" : 82.1
      }, {
        "date" : "17/05/2018",
        "progressPicture" : "http://www.google.com/example.jpg"
      }, {
        "date" : "18/05/2018",
        "weight" : 80.3
      } ]
    }
}
```

I have managed to get the latest log by ordering by key and limiting the result to 1, using the following code.

```
firebaseDatabase.getReference(USER_REFERENCE).child(firebaseAuth.currentUser?.uid).child(LOG_REFERENCE).orderByKey().limitToLast(1).
```

As can be seen from my JSON, a log doesn't necessarily have to have a weight value.

MY QUESTION:
How can I adjust my query so that I'll retrieve my latest log (so 1 log only based on key) where there is a value for weight?

Comment: Firebase Database queries can only order/filter on a single property. In many cases it is possible to combine the values you want to filter on into a single (synthetic) property. E.g. `"hasWeight_date": "true_20180518"`. For an example of this and other approaches, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase

Answer (score 1):

You can add new entry called `weight_log`,which will be updated once new weight is recorded , you can do it easily with `firebase functions` that will be triggered on each 
`/users/{userId}/weight_log/{iterationID}` create event

Then you can use `limitToLast(1)` on the new path

Generally it is good practice to flattening your data structure

Comment: this is not an answer, please answer the question properly

Comment: @Eminem To me this sounds like a valid answer. What part of it won't work in your opinion?

Comment: he can add some code,I think that would help the user more

Answer (score 0):

From reading the wiki you can only filter the data and check if there's a value for weight by adding a `ValueEventListener()` which will return a list of all the list where you have to loop through it and get you value

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#filtering_data